# Tests with mock work apart but don't work together

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark, mocking, pytest

I use pytest and unittest.mock libraries for testing my pyspark application and I encountered a strange behaviour. For demonstration I made a minimal example with 3 python files:

#### get_spark.py

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def get_spark():
    return SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

#### test_mock_spark.py

This test replaces Spark session with a mock object and I don't expect a real connection to start here.

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

def test_mock_spark():
    with patch('pyspark.sql.SparkSession', Mock()):
        from get_spark import get_spark
        spark = get_spark()
        spark.sql('abracadabra')  # This passes mock test but don't work with real Spark
```

#### test_useless.py

Other test with the import on the first line which fails the test session.

```py
from get_spark import *  # If I comment this line, tests will pass. If I don't, tests will fail

def test_useless():
    assert True
```

I will consider two versions of **test_useless.py**:

1. As defined above.
2. As defined above except the first line with the import is commented.

If I run tests separately with commands `pytest test_useless.py` and `pytest test_mock_spark.py`, everything will work in both cases.

But if I run tests together with the command `pytest`, in the first version test **test_mock_spark** will launch real Spark session and will fail with the error:

```shell
E   pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: 
E   mismatched input 'abracadabra' expecting ...
E   
E   == SQL ==
E   abracadabra
E   ^^^
```

The second version of the file passes all tests without any problem.
Why does the import on the first line in **test_useless.py** affects mocking and how to get rid of the error?

Comment: It's important to know "where to mock" - you should mock where the object is used and not where it's defined. So you should `patch('get_spark.SparkSession', Mock())`. The mock replaces the `SparkSession` for the `get_spark.py` module this way, which is what you want.

Comment: @PeterK, thank you for the explanation! As I understand, I should mock `pyspark.sql.SparkSession` specifying the path to the module where it is mentioned for the first time. 

But what if I’ll add a new test in the future which will import spark in a different way? Should I rewrite the mock each time I add a new test which changes the first mention of spark? May be there is a way to run the mock test independently?

Comment: Every test should only affect itself and not future tests. You should never rely on that your test or any other code would be the first to import. This is why you mock where it's used and not where it's defined - when you test a code area you can mock everything it uses since you know this code piece.