# Spring data JPA Junit tests work apart but don't work together

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, junit, spring-data-jpa

I'm going to test my app with next Junit tests:

```
@DataJpaTest
class UserNameTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserNameRepo repo;
    private UserName userName;

    @Test
    public void createUserName(){
        userName = new UserName("R","Lazy");
        repo.save(userName);
    }

    @Test
    public void findValueOfName(){
        userName = new UserName("R","Lazy");
        repo.save(userName);
        String result = repo.findValueOfName("R");
        assertEquals("Lazy",result);
    }
}
```

```
@DataJpaTest
class TodayTest {
    @Autowired
    TodayRepo repo;
    Today today;

    @Test
    public void createNewToday(){
        today = new Today("boy");
        repo.save(today);
    }

    @Test
    public void findValueOfToday(){
        today = new Today("boy");
        repo.save(today);
        String result = repo.findById(1).getMeaning();
        assertEquals("boy",result);
    }
}
```

```
@DataJpaTest
class DateTest {
    @Autowired
    private DateRepo repo;
    private Date date;

    @Test
    public void createNewDate(){
        date = new Date(", singing songs");
        repo.save(date);
    }

    @Test
    public void findValueOfDate(){
        date = new Date(", singing songs");
        repo.save(date);
        String expectedValue = ", singing songs";
        date = repo.findById(1);
        String actualValue = date.getMeaning();
        assertEquals(expectedValue,actualValue);
    }
}
```

My repositories are next:

```
@Component("userNameRepo")
public interface UserNameRepo extends CrudRepository<UserName, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select u.meaning from user_name_table u where u.letter = :letter", nativeQuery = true)
    String findValueOfName(@Param("letter") String letter);
}
```

```
@Component("todayRepo")
public interface TodayRepo extends CrudRepository<Today, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select * from today_table t where t.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    Today findById(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

```
@Component("dateRepo")
public interface DateRepo extends CrudRepository<Date,Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select * from date_table d where d.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    Date findById(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

If this test will be run apart they work well. But when I run them all together, the test `UserNameTest` works but not others.

The stacktrace of one of the test (another is similar) is next:

```
2022-08-11 08:31:00.724  INFO 18831 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@39b9dc35 testClass = DateTest, testInstance = com.ensei.funnyGame.entity.DateTest@118f2486, testMethod = findValueOfDate@DateTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@3976910 testClass = DateTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.ensei.funnyGame.FunnyGameApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@6e149395 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@66498326, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@6631f5ca, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@180fb796, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@212b5695, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@a0c6f9cd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@49c7b90e, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@2bed5828]; rollback [true]
Hibernate: insert into date_table (id, meaning) values (default, ?)
Hibernate: select * from date_table d where d.id = ?
2022-08-11 08:31:00.770  INFO 18831 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@39b9dc35 testClass = DateTest, testInstance = com.ensei.funnyGame.entity.DateTest@118f2486, testMethod = findValueOfDate@DateTest, testException = java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.ensei.funnyGame.entity.Date.getMeaning()" because "this.date" is null, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@3976910 testClass = DateTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.ensei.funnyGame.FunnyGameApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@6e149395 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@66498326, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@6631f5ca, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@180fb796, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@212b5695, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@a0c6f9cd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@49c7b90e, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.ensei.funnyGame.entity.Date.getMeaning()" because "this.date" is null

    at com.ensei.funnyGame.entity.DateTest.findValueOfDate(DateTest.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

I try to search solving of problem but found just similar problem on mock and without solution
[Tests with mock work apart but don't work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73221343/tests-with-mock-work-apart-but-dont-work-together)

I would be  grateful for any help.

Comment: what is this new Date(", singing songs")? Is this custom class or java.lang.Date?

Comment: I created it. It's usual entity as well as "UserName" and "Today". They are entities too.

Comment: The problem is your test. You assume the `id` is always 1... What you should do instead is use the `id` from the entity insetad of the hardcoded value of 1. Also your repository is basically defeating the purpose of Spring Data, ditch those `findById` methods (those already are on `CrudRepository`) and you don't need a native query a JPQL one will work as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried to use embedded method `findByID` but the problem was left (apart run test works, together doesn't work). The problem is `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present`. Could you, please, explain with example how `id` should be used instead of hardcoding because I don't imagine yet how it may be used without receiving of entity

Comment: Your `save` method returns the persisted entity. You can do a `findById(today.getId())` to have the generated id for the entity at hand. You are probably using a single sequence (`HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE`) for the ids of all your entities. Meaning if you run them alone it always will be 1, but when running multiple tests it will keep advancing and as the order isn't determined you don't know the id.

Comment: Great now remove those custom `findById` methods also the `@Component` doesn't add anything either, saves you another line of code :).

Comment: Already done :)